# Using send_keys() on a search/filter input field does not filter results in table

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

There is a table with a list of users and their email on a webpage. At the top of the page, is a search/filter input field that allows the user to type an email or username and filter for the result as he/she is typing.

**The problem: However, when I use the send_keys() method instead of doing this manually, nothing is filtered in the table view.**

This is happening on the Safari browser on the iPhone 7 Plus (real device, not simulator). Some other information:

- iOS version: 12.2
- Appium version: 1.13.0-beta.3
- Selenium version: 2.53.1
- Programming language: Python 2.7.15

In addition to `send_keys()`, i've tried to use `set_value()`, i've also tried to execute JS and setting the attribute `value`, and also tried to send key for each character (in a for loop with a delay between each character).

I'm expecting for example, element.send_keys("test1000@test.com) to filter the table view on the web page so that the only user that is displayed has the associated test1000@test.com email as it does when I go through the site manually.

In actuality, send_keys() does not do that and nothing in the table view gets filtered.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: post the event handler for the input field.

Comment: Does your app start searching as soon as you type text in search bar or you need to press search button or return/enter key while you do it manually? Were you able to send text to search input?

Comment: Sometimes we need to press certain keys after typing the text for search to start, so try to send keys like `Keys.TAB` 

`textbox.sendKeys("test1000@test.com"+Keys.TAB);`

Also after sending this try to do explicit wait for table contents

Comment: Sounds like there might be some javascript code, that is not triggered. Post the `html` code please.

Comment: @SubanDhyako, yes it filters out results as you type. And yes I was able to send text to the search input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Explicit wait for table to get populate in DOM
2. sendKeys search String and additional key Tab
   `textbox.sendKeys("test1000@test.com"+Keys.TAB)`
3. Explicit Wait for filter to get applied and table to get refreshed.
4. find elements for the newly populated table with applied filters.